# How can I save files from ftp?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, httpwebrequest

I have a methode that copy folder structure from ftp to local folder and then copy all files that consists in them:

```
public void CreateDirectories()
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Pass);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

    string soursePath = @"L:\Test";

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

    string directoryName = streamReader.ReadLine();

    while (directoryName != null)
    {
        //Create directories structure
        if (directoryName.StartsWith("I") && !directoryName.Contains("p"))
        {
            string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(soursePath, directoryName);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);

                //get file list and invoke DownLoad(string directoryName, string fileName)
                FtpWebRequest fileRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url + directoryName + "/");
                fileRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Pass);
                fileRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

                StreamReader fileStreamReader = new StreamReader(fileRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                string fileName = fileStreamReader.ReadLine();
                while (fileName != null)
                {
                    DownLoad(directoryName, fileName);
                    fileName = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }

            }
        }

        directoryName = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }

    request = null;
    streamReader = null;
}
```

and the methode that copy current file:

```
public void DownLoad(string directoryName, string fileName)
{
    string localPath = @"L:\Test\" + directoryName;

    FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.equip.me/prod/" + directoryName + "/" + fileName);
    requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Pass);
    requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
    FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

    int Length = 2048;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    }

    responseStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();

    requestFileDownload = null;
    responseFileDownload = null;
}
```

But in line   Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream(); it stop for nearly 40 seconds and then throw an exeption of timeout, and no one file has not been saved (file is small  - 50 kb)

Comment: is your firewall open for FTP requests?

Comment: saving folder structure is working so the problem is not associated with firewall

Comment: Is it failing for a particular file? In a particular Directory? Is maybe the FTP server limiting the number of active connections (you have already two connections going when you start the download)

Comment: @revolutionkpi - I could be wrong, but I believe the FtpWebRequest will use the passive method by default for transferring files (which wouldn't apply to listing/navigating the directories). In passive mode a second connection will be established on a random port to transfer the data. As rene said, this is likely a firewall problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you should try is to turn [passive mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive.aspx) off since this is automatically blocked by most firewalls, but is the default mode of operation for ftpWebRequest.

Just below this line:

```
requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

and this one:

```
requestFileDownload.UsePassive = false;
```